# How to prove this equation in terms of expectation in probability?

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider the following problem of empirical Bayesian estimation of
variances. Let $S_i^2$ be the sample variances satisfying

$\frac{S_i^2}{\sigma_i^2} | \sigma_i^2 \sim \frac{\chi_d^2}{d}, i=1,2,...,n$

Assume the prior on $\sigma_i^2$ is followed by inverted gamma distribution ($\alpha, \beta$). It can be shown that

$E (\log \sigma_i^2) = \log \beta - \psi (\alpha)$

Let $\mu_d = E \log \frac{\chi_d^2}{d}$ be a constant.

The questio is to show that $E (\log S_i^2) = \mu_d + \log \beta - \psi (\alpha)$.

I basically know how to do that. But I am not satisfied with the details in my steps:

First notice that we only need to show $E (\log S_i^2) = E (\log \frac{\chi_d^2}{d}  \sigma_i^2)$

Starting here I am not satisfied. $\frac{S_i^2}{\sigma_i^2} | \sigma_i^2 \sim \frac{\chi_d^2}{d}$. Thus, it is kind of like $S_i^2 \sim \frac{\chi_d^2}{d} \sigma_i^2$

It looks natural but I don't know what the rigorous way should be.